# SQL Server, views usage count

Tags: t-sql, excel, sql-server-2005, view

My scenario is like this:
I have a couple of views in my databse (SQL Server 2005).
These views are queried from Excel across the organization.

My goal is to identify those views which have not been used by anyone for a long time.

Is there a way to count the number of times a view has been requested since a specific date?

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 2):

You can use following query to get some queries those executed. You can place "Like" operator in dest.text field to check for views.

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.text AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DES
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* a combination of DMVs and sysobjects could tell you this. This should hopefully show you all queries run that refer to a view, the name of the view, when it was last run etc.

```
SELECT s2.text AS Query,
       so.name AS ViewName,
       creation_time,
       last_execution_time,
       execution_count
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2
       INNER JOIN sys.objects so
         ON so.object_id = s2.objectid
AND so.type = 'V'
```

Comment: Hello Bridge! Thanks for the answer. i tried using your query, but i get an empty result. It seems like views do not exists in the sys.dm_exec_query_stats table.

Comment: @avi Perhaps the table only refers to executable objects?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you'll be able to do this unless you are running a trace 24/7.  You could turn on auditing in order to monitor it.  But, it would be a big task for however has to read through the logs.